# Problems in running AWS CLI bash command within Java

Tags: java, bash, aws-cli

I'm trying to run an AWS command within Java code (in Linux). Like always, I try to run the bash command like this in Java. But I wonder it doesn't show anything. And just prints `Exited with error code : 2`. When I just run `aws ls help` in bash, it works.

What is the problem? How to solve it?

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class TestCMD {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
                ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder();
                processBuilder.command("bash", "-c", "aws ls help");

                try {
                        Process process = processBuilder.start();
                        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

                        String line;
                        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                                System.out.println(line);
                        }
                        int exitCode = process.waitFor();
                        System.out.println("\nExited with error code : " + exitCode);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: This looks ok to me - can you verify that bash exists? Can you use `/bin/bash` (if that exists) instead of `bash`?

Comment: Still the same. It says `Exited with error code : 2`

Comment: what about `command("bash", "-c", "aws", "ls", "help");` ? Errorcode 2 means something like "file not found". If bash can be found, it has to be one of the other parameters.

Comment: still the same `Exited with error code : 2`.

Comment: how do you run this in your terminal?

Comment: just `aws ls help`.

Answer (score 1):

The Java code is not the problem. It works fine, what you can check by replacing the `command` with

```
processBuilder.command("bash", "-c", "echo 1 2 3");
```

You have 2 "problems".
The first problem is that `aws` writes its output to stderr, not stdout.
The second problem is that `aws` returns 2 where `0` would be IMHO better.
You can test this on the commandline with:

```
aws ls help 2>/dev/null; echo $?
```

The problems can be fixed with

```
processBuilder.command("bash", "-c", "/usr/bin/aws ls help 2>&1; true");
```